# UINavigationItem craziness from pushing view controllers with no animation?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

---

I am pushing a `viewController` onto the `UINavigationController` with animation, and the controller being pushed on is basically doing something like:

**--- app delegate:**

```
[((UINavigationController *)window.rootViewController) pushViewController:initialController animated:YES];
```

**--- initial controller:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if (self.shouldSkipThisController) {
      SomeOtherViewController *someOther = [[SomeOtherViewController alloc] init];
      [self.navigationController pushViewController:someOther animated:NO];
    }
}
```

This is causing some CRAZY behavior which I don't understand at all.  Basically, it seems like the navigation items set on `SomeOtherViewController` are being covered up by some strange other button that has the name of the title in a back button.  It looks like although `SomeOtherViewController` is setting it's own left and right navigation items, they are covered up by the "default" back button--- and then if I tap on that back button, then just the navigation bar at the top animates-- and THEN `SomeOtherViewController`'s navigation items are then there.

The only thing I could find that sort of worked was to either 1) not animate the push of the initial view controller in the app delegate, or 2) move the `shouldSkipThisController` condition into `viewDidAppear`: method.

However, neither of those options are ideal...  Any help could be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How did you initialize UINavigationController in AppDelgate?

Comment: Why are you pushing initialViewController then immediately pushing SomeOtherViewController? What's the purpose of doing that?

Comment: rdelmar: mainly because "initialController" acts as a delegate for other objects, so it's convenient for it to still be involved for callbacks, etc.